# saving an lda model for prediction

Tags: python, lda

How can I save an lda model and call it for future prediction in another function

```
data=pd.DataFrame(ivector_list,index=label)

data.to_csv("ivector/Ivector.csv")
Y=data.index
X=data.reset_index(drop=True)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.25,random_state=50)

lda = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(n_components = 50)
model=lda.fit_transform(X_train,y_train)
predictions = lda.predict(X_test)
saved_model=pickle.dumps(model)
```

but when I try using saved_model to predict I get this error

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'predict'

pre=saved_model.predict(d1)
```

Comment: You have to load the model, the saved model only have the weights associated with the particular model.  (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html)

Comment: I loaded the model by using this saved_model=pickle.loads(model) and still got this error TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'list'